# python urllib.request.urlopen doesn't follow redirect

Tags: python, redirect, urllib

I'm using python 3.2.2. If I try to do:

```
urllib.request.urlopen('https://pypi.python.org/simple/babel')
```

I get following error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "solver.py", line 93, in <module>
      generateMetadata('babel')
    File "solver.py", line 76, in generateMetadata
      linklist = parseURL(name)
    File "solver.py", line 20, in parseURL
      resp = opener.open(REP_URL+name+'/')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 375, in open
      response = meth(req, response)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 487, in http_response
      'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 407, in error
      result = self._call_chain(*args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 347, in _call_chain
      result = func(*args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 560, in http_error_302
      headers, fp)
  urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 301: Moved Permanently - Redirection to url '/simple/Babel' is not allowed
```

After searching I found that it should handle redirects automatically.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Python 3.2.3.

Comment: Just before that exception is the line `if urlparts.scheme not in ('http', 'https', 'ftp', ''):`. Your URL must be dodgy, check that it uses the correct scheme.

Comment: I tested the same line with python 3.2.3 and 3.3 and both worked. It can't be that i hit the one bug, that exists in only my subversion, can it?

Comment: What URL are you passing in when you get this error? Look at `repr(url)` to make sure you catch any special characters.

Comment: Hrm, looking at the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/urllib/request.py#l540) again I suspect that the response was corrupted instead.

Comment: The one at the top of my post. Someone here now figured out, that this was a bug in python 3.2.0 to 3.2.2 . The '' in urlparts.scheme is missing in those versions. Can i somehow close this post now? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could post a self-answer below; it might bite others too. Here is a reference to the bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue13696

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems, there is a bug in the Python Versions 3.2.0 to 3.2.2.

If you know the user of your program are gonna use this version, you can try monkey patching. (Overwriting the Module with the patched one from 3.2.3 if they're using one of the faulted versions)

Theres the corresponding Bug report: http://bugs.python.org/issue13696

Comment: You may want to include a link to the bug report I gave you.